# Swift protocol interacting with objective-c ViewController Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, protocols

I am trying to trigger a function from my view controller class in a swift class using a protocol.

```
@objc protocol KestrelDeviceConnectDelegate: AnyObject {    
    func readingIsOver()    
}

class KestrelDeviceConnect: NSObject {    

    weak var delegate: KestrelDeviceConnectDelegate?

    func timerAction() {    
        timerCounter += 1
        if(timerCounter >= 20){
            progressHUD.hide()
            timerCounter = 0
            timer.invalidate()
            self.delegate?.readingIsOver()

            //present kestrel alert
        }
    }
}
```

in the view controller class viewdidload

```
KestrelDeviceConnect *bluetoothManager = [[KestrelDeviceConnect alloc]init];
bluetoothManager.delegate = self;
```

function I want to be called from my swift class

```
- (void)readingIsOver {
    [[self logConditionsButton] setHidden:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to hold a strong reference by making `bluetoothManager` an instance variable

```
KestrelDeviceConnect *bluetoothManager;
```

---

```
bluetoothManager = [[KestrelDeviceConnect alloc]init];
```

Comment: That didn't change anything

Comment: this `KestrelDeviceConnect *bluetoothManager;` outside `viewDidLoad` ?

Comment: self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.timerAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

Comment: I know the if statement in the timerAction function executes, but self.delegate?.readingIsOver() doesnt do anything

Comment: do `print( self.delegate)` to see if nil , also where & when in terms of order you run that timer

Comment: it prints "nil"

Comment: the timer is started when a function in the the file is called